# What makes a chromecast make a request with 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin'?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

Basically I have a video on rackspace that I think has the right cors headers, same headers I've always used and used to work fine.

The Chromecast will first make a request like this:

`curl 'video.m3u8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.81 Safari/537.36 CrKey/1.42.172094' -H 'Origin: https://myreceiverhost' --compressed --insecure`

And it will get back:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Headers: *
Cache-Control: public, max-age=259129
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 942
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2019 16:11:06 GMT
ETag: b0a3cc7fda814676936fcf133e83fb4a
Expires: Tue, 17 Sep 2019 16:09:55 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 Sep 2019 16:09:43 GMT
X-Timestamp: 1568477382.09591
X-Trans-Id: txf975724d827845e38ee6f-005d7d10f1iad3
```

Then it will make a similar request that also works:

`curl 'video.m3u8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.81 Safari/537.36 CrKey/1.42.172094' -H 'Origin: https://myreceiverhost' --compressed --insecure`

With this response:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Headers: *
Cache-Control: public, max-age=259129
Content-Length: 942
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2019 16:11:06 GMT
ETag: b0a3cc7fda814676936fcf133e83fb4a
Expires: Tue, 17 Sep 2019 16:09:55 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 Sep 2019 16:09:43 GMT
X-Timestamp: 1568477382.09591
X-Trans-Id: txf975724d827845e38ee6f-005d7d10f1iad3
```

But then it will make this request:

`curl 'https://video.m3u8' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin' -H 'Referer: myreceiverhost/fullpath' --compressed`

And that fails.

Why is it doing that? I've never seen it do that before.

Edit: something very odd I just noticed. I have two m3u8 videos on the same aws s3 bucket, one has this issue, the other one doesn't. Headers are identical.

Comment: i think if a `request-mode` is both `same-origin` and `cors`, actually you shoud choose `cors` header for `Sec-Fetch-Mode` while you will refer to the relation of request-initiator and resources-host with another header which is `sec-fetch-site: same-origin`